# Ubuntu Server etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

E: Malformed entry 3 in list file etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse)

I don't know which one the malformed entry points to. Can anybody help me with that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEkQZ.png

[The sources.list file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEkQZ.png)

Comment: Please do not add screenshots behind links. Add the contents of the files directly to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie for Ubuntu Server and don't know how to extract that from VM on Win10.

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces at start of lines that refer to `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu`.

Comment: I misconfiged the Mirror setting during installation, with that corrected then the error went away. I can't try your solution now, but thanks all the same.